# entry "status" not honoured on import [json / solspace importer]

Tags: solspace-importer

When I import a json file the Status is neglected. All imported items have the status "Closed" after an import when the value of the imported status field is set to "Open" and I have tried "open" just like in the docs.
The import is completing successfully but the status setting is not being honoured.
The status field is being recognised in the import profile settings.

Hope someone can help :)

(EE2.9.2 / importer 2.2.5)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I did not have the default status group linked to that particular channel. That why Importer could not apply the 'Open' status...

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to fix up your imported data one time and don't need to repeat the import the simplest solution might be a quick SQL query. :)